# Convert VBA to Google Apps Script

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to convert my VBA to something I can use for Google Apps Script.

This is my VBA Code

`Function InteriorColor(CellColor As Range)
Application.Volatile
InteriorColor = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function`

But i don't know how to convert that to a Google Apps Script

Comment: Voting to close this as too broad, you have not even included an attempt at converting it yourself.

Comment: So you're trying to change the background color of a cell/range of cells?

Answer (score 1):

This will set the color of a range in a spreadsheet:

```
function setColor(range,color) {
  var range=range||"Sheet177!A1:G10";//default range
  var color=color||"#ffff00";//default color
  try {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(range).setBackground(color);//has to be range in form of SheetName!A1:G10
    //sets the background to yellow as the default
  }
  catch(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e);
  }
}
```

[Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/)

[Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: I'm curious, is there a purpose or some advantage to declaring range with a logical `or` or is this some special syntax to declare the type of the variable? To be specific I'm referring to `var color=color||"#ffff00";`

Comment: It's just an easy way to get a default if the parameter `color` is not provided.  You could also say `var color=(color!="undefined")?color:'#ffff00';`

Comment: Oh that's neat, thank you for explaining